# Create random ip and store in database with username

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

I want to make a "fake skype resolver" just for troll.
Now i made a random IP generator

```
<?php $randIP = "".mt_rand(0,255).".".mt_rand(0,255).".".mt_rand(0,255).".".mt_rand(0,255); ?>
```

Now i want to store them in a database with the user they have posted:

```
<?php


     if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $randIP = "".mt_rand(0,255).".".mt_rand(0,255).".".mt_rand(0,255).".".mt_rand(0,255);
        echo 'The IP of '.$username.' is '.$randIP.';
?>

        <form action="">
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" size="40" value="Habbo">
        </form>
<input type="hidden" id="send" name="send" value=Resolve IP">
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Resolve IP">
```

The problem now is if they resolved again then it shows a new IP adres, how can i make that it shows the same IP like befour?

Comment: A session cookie? Using a consistent hash of the `username` value?

Answer (score 0):

To do this you have to save results to database using eg. `PDO`.

Also you can use cookies. In your case it should be enough.
Just use `setcookie` function.